# XSLT: assign ids from one document to the other iterating over multiple same values

Tags: xml, xslt, position, xslt-2.0

Can anyone help me out with the following problem? I have two XML docs. A TEI that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
    <body>
        <div>
            <head>IN ADVENTU DOMINI</head>
            <div type="time:1">
                <ab ana="#head">
                    <hi>aaaa</hi>
                </ab>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <head>FERIA II.</head>
            <div type="time:1">
                <ab ana="#head">
                    <hi>bbbb</hi>
                </ab>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <head>FERIA III.</head>
            <div type="time:1">
                <ab ana="#head">
                    <hi>cccc</hi>
                </ab>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <head>DOMINICA</head>
            <div type="time:1">
                <ab ana="#head">
                    <hi>dddd</hi>
                </ab>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <head>FERIA II.</head>
            <div type="time:1">
                <ab ana="#head">
                    <hi>eeee</hi>
                </ab>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <head>FERIA III.</head>
            <div type="time:1">
                <ab ana="#head">
                    <hi>ffff</hi>
                </ab>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</text>
```

and a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
        <row>
            <cell>IN ADVENTU DOMINI</cell>
            <cell>1234</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>FERIA II.</cell>
            <cell>1200</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>FERIA III.</cell>
            <cell>1211</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>DOMINICA</cell>
            <cell>1299</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>FERIA II.</cell>
            <cell>9999</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>FERIA III.</cell>
            <cell>8888</cell>
        </row>
</table>
```

Now I want to add ids (found in the second `<cell>` element of the table) to those elements of the TEI that have the same value in `<head>` as in the first `<cell>` element of the table. I have written the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="t:head">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="count(current())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ids" select="document('feasts.xml')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="row" select="$ids//row[cell[1]=current()][position()=$pos]"/>

            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:if test="$row!=''">
                    <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
                        <xsl:text>CDB.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$row/cell[2]"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
            </xsl:copy>

 </xsl:template>
```

I know I have to do something with the $pos variable but I don't know how to get the correct ids from the table and not just the first one. Desired output for the `<head>` elements would be:

```
        <head xml:id="CDB.1234">IN ADVENTU DOMINI</head>

        <head xml:id="CDB.1200">FERIA II.</head>

        <head xml:id="CDB.1211">FERIA III.</head>

        <head xml:id="CDB.1299">DOMINICA</head>

        <head xml:id="CDB.9999">FERIA II.</head>

        <head xml:id="CDB.8888">FERIA III.</head>
```

Comment: `count(current())` will always return 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always best to use **keys** to resolve cross-references:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="ids" select="document('feasts.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="grp" match="head" use="." />
<xsl:key name="id" match="row" use="cell[1]" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="head">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="index-of(key('grp', .)/generate-id(), generate-id())"/>
    <head xml:id="CDB.{key('id', ., $ids)[$i]/cell[2]}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </head>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
   <body>
      <div>
         <head xml:id="CDB.1234">IN ADVENTU DOMINI</head>
         <div type="time:1">
            <ab ana="#head">
               <hi>aaaa</hi>
            </ab>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <head xml:id="CDB.1200">FERIA II.</head>
         <div type="time:1">
            <ab ana="#head">
               <hi>bbbb</hi>
            </ab>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <head xml:id="CDB.1211">FERIA III.</head>
         <div type="time:1">
            <ab ana="#head">
               <hi>cccc</hi>
            </ab>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <head xml:id="CDB.1299">DOMINICA</head>
         <div type="time:1">
            <ab ana="#head">
               <hi>dddd</hi>
            </ab>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <head xml:id="CDB.9999">FERIA II.</head>
         <div type="time:1">
            <ab ana="#head">
               <hi>eeee</hi>
            </ab>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <head xml:id="CDB.8888">FERIA III.</head>
         <div type="time:1">
            <ab ana="#head">
               <hi>ffff</hi>
            </ab>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</text>
```

Comment: It should be `<head xml:id="CDB.{key('id', ., $ids)[$i]/cell[2]}">`, no?

Comment: Yeah, I  guess so.

Comment: you are absolutely right. sorry. it's gotta have to do with my real input. I will have to figure that out. thanks a lot for your help!!